# Focus issue on ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have a Search `Activity`, whose layout file is as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                <LinearLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white2" >

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/et_search"
                        android:layout_width="280dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:drawableRight="@drawable/search_20"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:hint="Search by name" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/grey05"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
                        android:layout_width="1dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        android:text="Name"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
                    </TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_sno"
                        android:layout_width="1dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        android:text="Serial No."
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
                    </TextView>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_type"
                        android:layout_width="1dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.25"
                        android:text="Type"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" >
                    </TextView>
                </LinearLayout>

                <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/listView1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dip"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:transcriptMode="normal" >
                </ListView>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_chkin"
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="50dip"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                        android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/custombutton"
                        android:text="Submit" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/btn_chkout"
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="50dip"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:background="@drawable/custombutton"
                        android:text="Cancel" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
```

A Search `EditText` on top, a list view in the center and two buttons at the bottom of the screen.

I am unable to focus one item in the Listview.
In the layout file for listview adapter, I have set `android:clickable="false"
        android:focusable="false"`
Still when I select an item, the selected item doesn't get highlighted ..
I have also tried to put following code in the `onItemClick`

## 1

```
  // @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
            long id) {

        if (lview3 != null) {
            lview3.getChildAt(prevPos).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);         
            lview3.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        }
        prevPos = position;
    }
```

## 2

```
    // @Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
        long id) {
      lview3.setSelection(position);
}
```

For #1 works absolutely fine on emulator, but on my Samsung Galaxy Y, it says **"Application has stopped unexpectedly.Please try again" **

For #2 the item is highlighted as long as I touch the item on the screen, as soon as I remove my finger, the highlight color is gone.

My listview_row.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linLayout_search"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"        
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_sno"
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"       
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_type"
        android:layout_width="1dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.30"        
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: android:clickable="false" android:focusable="false" set these attribute true.

Comment: Don't check ur app in emulator, If u check with any android phone u can catch all the bugs.

Comment: Sorry I also had to show my layout file for each row in the listview. </br> @Akki: I did set `android:clickable="false" android:focusable="false"` to true in my layout file which I had tried before also. In this case it does highlight the selected item but just paint two horizontal line above and below the selected row in the List.

Comment: I feel that maybe the `TextView`s used in the adapter to create `View` for each row in the list are consuming the click event.Therefore I have set the clickable and focusable to false.

Comment: Even tried setting `lview3.setItemsCanFocus(true);` in `onCreate()` and `lview3.setItemChecked(position, true);` in `onItemClick()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yipeee... https://stackoverflow.com/a/10277370/840520
This solved the problem. Here's what I added..in the `getView()` of my `ListAdapter`

```
    // set selected item
    LinearLayout activeItem = (LinearLayout) convertView;

    if (position == SearchAssetActivity.selectedItem){
        activeItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
        // for focus on it
        int top = (activeItem == null) ? 0 : activeItem.getTop();
        ((ListView) parent).setSelectionFromTop(position, top);
    }
    else{
        activeItem.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You have selection mode in listview .This is the standard code for making persistant selections in list view

```
// inside onCreate method
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // Make the newly clicked item the currently selected one.
    getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
}
```

Before this you need to set list view item's layout background with a selector

```
android:background="@drawable/activated_background"
```

activated_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:exitFadeDuration="400">

    <item android:drawable="#ff0099cc" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="#ff0099cc" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="#ff0099cc" android:state_activated="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>

</selector>
```