# How to select an item from a circular listView?

Tags: android, timer

[image]

I would like to create the above layout.It is MI Redmi in-built timer(clock) app.I have created something like this.

[image]

**How to highlight an particular item from the listView (circular listView) to show selected item**

Comment: Its not circlular list view; its wheelview.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053765/how-to-make-a-wheel-picker

Comment: Plz help show me some reference.I don't know what it is.(Assumed it as such)

Answer (score 0):

ListView::setSelection(int position) is the attribute you can use to highlight your item.for more information you can refer to this link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2042278/android-listview-selection-problem)